# Android realm database for local font

Tags: android, realm

I have a student table and name with local font.

So when I search student from local. I retrieve data like below code from real database.

```
RealmResults<Students> studentList = realm.where(Students.class).contains("name",query).findAll();
```

but I got 0 (zero ) size in studentList. But when i search with english name, it fine.
I would like to know, does realm support local language or not? or do i need something in configuration?

Comment: Show your table structure

Comment: @KulsDroid just update with realm browser table.

Comment: it should work, but not for case-insensitive (outside of A-Z)